# .Net how to sign a certificate request (.csr) from a CA server

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have generated a csr request using .net ( System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.CertificateRequest.CreateSigningRequest()).

I have a CA in a different server which I want the csr to be signed off.

Manually I get it signed off by running command in the CA server:
certreq -submit -attrib "CertificateTemplate:WebServer" "xyz.csr"

How do I do the same using .net libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ICertRequest::Submit` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certcli/nf-certcli-icertrequest-submit.

`ICertRequest` COM interface is defined in certcli.dll which you must reference in VS project.